# How to fetch Google search query trending data if "Not enough search volume to show graphs"?

Tags: google-search

I'm searching for trending of a certain first Google Instant recommendation. Google Trends says not enough search volume to show graphs.

However since it's the first recommendation, I do believe there is some search volume. An answer in StackOverflow suggested using Google Insight, which has already been merged into Trends.

Is there any API I can use to enquiry the original data?

Answer (score 0):

Realize I'm reviving an old question, but since this is still an issue; if you are conducting non-profit research with an organization you can request access to the Google Trends API, which allows you to query Google Trends using Python. You can request access with this [form](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSenHdGiGl1YF-7rVDDmmulN8R-ra9MnGLLs7gIIaAX9VHPdPg/viewform).

Using the GetQueryVolumes Trends function you can get more detailed search volumes.